Modelo Vista Controlador error could not find driver
Estoy estudiando en píldoras informáticas de Youtube y estoy con PHP en ESTE VIDEO y tengo este problema "Error could not find driver". Reviso todos los códigos pero no logro dar con algun problema, hasta donde se debe ser algo del WampServer busque soluciones pero no logro dar con la adecuada aquí les envío todos los códigos necesarios estoy usando la version de wamp 3.3.5 64 bits:
C:\wamp64\www\Curso php\MVC\index.php:
<?php
    require_once("Controlador/Productos_controlador.php");  
?>

C:\wamp64\www\Curso php\MVC\Controlador\Productos_controlador.php
<?php  
    require_once("Modelo/Productos_modelo.php");
    $productos=new Productos_model(); 
    $matrizProductos=$productos->get_productos();   
    require_once("Vista/Productos_view.php");
    
?>

C:\wamp64\www\Curso php\MVC\Modelo\Conectar.php
<?php 
    class Conectar{
        static public function conexion(){
            try{
                $conexion=new PDO('myslq:host=localhost; dbname=pruebas','root','');
                $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $conexion->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
                
                }catch(Exception $e){
                    die("Error" . $e->getMessage());
                    echo "Linea del error: " . $e->getLine();   
                    }
                return $conexion;
            }
        }
?>

C:\wamp64\www\Curso php\MVC\Modelo\Productos_modelo.php
<?php  
    class Productos_model{
        private $db;
        private $productos;
        public function __construct(){// Se encarga de conectar a BBDD
            require_once("Modelo/Conectar.php");/*La sentencia require_once es idéntica a require excepto que PHP verificará si el archivo ya ha sido incluido y si es así, no se incluye (require) de nuevo.*/
            $this->db=Conectar::conexion();
            $this->productos=array();
            }
        public function get_productos(){// Se encarga de devolver los productos de la tabla
            $consulta=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM productos");
            while($fila=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $this->productos[]=$fila;
                }
            return $this->productos;
            }
        }
?>

C:\wamp64\www\Curso php\MVC\Vista\Productos_view.php
<style>
    td{
        border:1px dotted #FF0000;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr><td>NOMBRE DEL ARTÍCULO</td>
<?php
    foreach($matrizProductos as $registro){
        echo "<tr><td>" . $registro["NOMBREARTÍCULO"] . "</td></tr>";
        }
?>
</table>

Desde ya muchas gracias por su atención.

Asumiendo que tienes PDO debidamente instalado en tu servidor, el error Could not find driver estaría ocurriendo debido a que tienes un error en el DSN que le pasas al constructor de PDO: has escrito myslq cuando debe ser mysql, por eso PDO interpreta que intentas conectarte a un SGBD extraño para el cual él no tiene un controlador.
También, conviene no dejar espacios en blanco en el DSN, si mal no recuerdo, esto era motivo de error en versiones anteriores de PHP.
Así debería funcionar:
$conexion=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas','root','');

Otras mejoras

El charset lo puedes pasar también en el DSN, agregándolo con un punto y coma.

Los atributos los puedes pasar como array asociativo en un cuarto parámetro del constructor.

En bloques try ... catch, conviene hacer el return desde dentro del bloque try. Y cuando trabajas con excepciones, conviene propagarlas, de lo contrario no tendrás un manejo de errores coherente con respecto al llamador. Esto es más complejo, lo comento porque tiene relación con lo de hacer el return dentro del try.

Evita mostrar en pantalla mensajes de error internos, los cuales pueden revelar información sensible, como el nombre de usuario de la base de datos. Incluso en el pasado, PDO revelaba la constraseña que se usaba para la conexión. Menos mal que este fallo fue corregido en las últimas versiones de PHP.


Haciendo eso, podrías quitar estas dos líneas, porque tendrás tu instancia completamente preparada desde el constructor, sin tener que modificarla a posteriori:
$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conexion->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

Si aplicamos estas mejoras, el código quedaría así:
class Conectar{
    static public function conexion(){
        try{
            return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas;charset=UTF8','root','',[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);             
        }catch(Exception $e){
            #Aquí convendría propagar la Excepción
            #Por el momento retornamos null
            #Y evita mostrar mensajes de error internos
            #Pueden revelar información sensible
            return null;
        }
    }
}


muchas gracias por el consejo la verdad si tengo un largo camino como se me pudo pasar por alto algo asi solo demuestra lo novato que soy jaajjaajaj y por las mejoras te lo super agradesco y lo pondre en practica de inmediato siempre hay algo nuevo que aprender y eso me emociona mucho desde ya muy agradecido
